# Authentication Google with Firebase doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have an application, where people need to log in with Google. I'm using Firebase for this, but, when I'm trying to login with Google, it gives an error and types in Toast `"Something wrong, Log in failed".`

In console it says:

`You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE`

I'm getting credential from SSH1, and I have put them in application, but it doesn't work.

Write step by step in details how to correctly get credential from SSH1, and how and where I should add it in app.

Comment: When i'm compiled app previously, it worked, but when i add it to Google Play it stopped work for one day, but on the next day it start to work. Why it happened, and how i shoud do right

Comment: have you added the SHA-1 for all the machine you are using to build the release version on firebase ?

Comment: Yes, i did it..

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: first add this dependency**

- firebase_core: ^1.0.1
- firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
- google_sign_in: ^5.0.0

**Step 2 : create project in firebase**

**Step 3 :  create google_login_repository.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class Authentication {
  static Future<User?> signInWithGoogle({required BuildContext context}) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;

    if (kIsWeb) {
      GoogleAuthProvider authProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();

      try {
        final UserCredential userCredential =
            await auth.signInWithPopup(authProvider);

        user = userCredential.user;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        try {
          final UserCredential userCredential =
              await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

          user = userCredential.user;
          if(userCredential.user != null){
            // Navigate home screen
          }

        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            // ...
          } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
            // ...
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // ...
        }
      }
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

**Step 4 :  sign-out**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class Authentication {
  static Future<void> signOut({required BuildContext context}) async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    try {
      if (!kIsWeb) {
        await googleSignIn.signOut();
      }
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        Authentication.customSnackBar(
          content: 'Error signing out. Try again.',
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 5 : SnackBar**

static SnackBar customSnackBar({required String content}) {
return SnackBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.black,
content: Text(
content,
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, letterSpacing: 0.5),
),
);
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).